# How can you call Augur as an oracle from an Ethereum smart contract in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, augur

The Augur FAQ states it possible to use it as an oracle:

http://blog.augur.net/faq-frequently-asked-questions/

*“Will other contracts be able to query Augur outcomes?*

*Yes, Augur is actually 2 products that can be used alone. One is a prediction market, the other is an **oracle**. The results from the oracle service are publicly available, and anyone can pay what will likely amount to several dollars to have an official statement regarding the objective truth about a subject.”*

However, the Augur API documentation doesn't seem to provide any information on how to call it from an Ethereum smart contract.

Is it already possible to call Augur as an oracle from an Ethereum smart contract in Solidity? How can you do it?

Comment: Hi there. I think it'd be better to as on their SE page: https://augur.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://augur.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion. I will repost the question there then.